# vim: open file and enable autoread in one command

Tags: vim

G'day!

I have log file ~/log.txt and want to open it with vim and enable autoread option ( that makes vim reload file on change ) in single command.
I don't want to enable autoread manually with

```
:set autoread
```

I don't want to change .vimrc because I want autoread work only for log file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell Vim in your `.vimrc` file to add settings only to specific files.

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead /home/foo/log.txt setlocal autoread
```

This autocommand will enable `autoread` automatically as soon as you open the log file.

Type `:help :autocmd` for an in-depth documentation of autocommands.

Comment: It helped! Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure! If an answer helped you, please don't forget to accept it. (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers )